# Why the date values are different in Javascript

Tags: javascript

All:

Quick question why the Javascript Date object built from a milsec number are different:

```
var ms = 1524862189829
new Date(1524862189829)
Fri Apr 27 2018 13:49:49 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)
Date(1524862189829)
"Mon Apr 30 2018 15:29:44 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)"
```

one shows Apr 27, but the other shows Apr 30, also the time are not same,  which one is correct? This is the result from Chrome 65 console

Thanks

```js
const ms = 1524862189829;
const d0 = new Date(ms);
const d1 = Date(ms);

const pd0 = document.getElementById('date0');
const pd1 = document.getElementById('date1');

pd0.innerText = d0.toString();
pd1.innerText = d1.toString();
```

```html
<p id="date0">
</p>
<p id="date1">
</p>
```

Comment: Don't forget to use the search ;)

Comment: @FelixKling Thanks, sometimes I just have no idea what key word I should search. But many thanks

Comment: I literally just searched for `Date vs new Date`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling the `Date()` constructor without `new` just gives you the current date and time information as a string. It doesn't pay attention to the parameter you pass at all.